# Expose data from same back end to multiple clients

Tags: android, web-services, api, web-applications

I am a new guy to full stack web application development. I want to design a web application which has data stored in say back end databases. Now I want to design a desktop web client as well as android application which will be able to fetch data from back end. So how do I need to start? What APIs can be used or how can I expose data from same back end to multiple clients?

Also I want to handle massive amount of request. How to design such a system? What to use in back end to store data and handle requests efficiently.

Any video / document / reference containing useful information will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you have a whole forest of questions to settle. You are going to need to go do your own research on such things as algorithms and data flow for your application before you can make any reasonable choice of platform. Here are a couple of basic ideas to get you going: 1) look at Java and Node.js. There are lots of other possible platforms but chances are you will end up using one of those two. Try to think about what the actual code you will generate in each of those will look like. A little or a lot? 2) Just store your data in files, most probably using JSON. Maybe you will end up doing something more fancy after you figure out where you are going with your project, but you will be surprised how well the simple file-based solution will scale.

When you have done a bunch more research, and maybe even coded up a few ideas on your platform of choice, then come back and massively edit your question. Only then will specific suggestions for tool choices be possible.

Comment: I will decide about what to do but I literally have very little idea about API. Exposing data to multiple clients. Which API I can research on? Certainly I am not willing to call file I/O or database operations every time an user does some transaction.

Comment: Algorithms and data flow come before API... way before.